# Load a text file into a HashMap<Integer, List<String>> java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am stuck in loading file elements using java

The text file contents are like below

```
1 SXABC SXPQR SXRYZ
2 SXTYU SXHIN SXOHJA SXYUHIANDH SXYUOIO
3 SXTAH SBUC SIJN SIOJ
```

Below is the code I am trying to write load data from this file to  HASHMAP of `Integer`s and `List<String>`

```
public class Dataset {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

         Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.csv"));
         String line = null;

         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
             try { 
                 String[] values=line.split(" ");
                 int rating = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
                 List<String> list =  new ArrayList<String>();
                 list.add(values[1]);
                 map.put(rating, list);
            } catch (Exception e) {}

            System.out.println(map);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sagarika, Welcome to Stack Overflow :). Will be better if you inform the issue on your question, what is happening? are you getting an exception? The data is not as you expect ?

Comment: {}
{2=[SXABC ]}
{2=[SXABC ], 3=[SXTAH ]}

This is the output I am getting, While it is supposed to be something like 

1=[SXABC,SXPQR,SXRYZ]

I want to know should I avoid the first element and add the rest of the elements as list to my hashmap llist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of :

```
list.add(values[1]);
```

just do :

```
for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
   list.add(values[i]);
}
```

Comment: funkyjelly it skips the first element, thanks for your answer